How would one go about getting a Regeneration potion with a duration of 8 minutes and an amplifier level of 3 in Minecraft?
The command below is the one I have already tried although I am not sure as to how to change the amplifier level or the duration of the potion itself:
/give AbvoltTheBest minecraft:potion[minecraft:potion_contents="regeneration", minecraft:max_stack_size=1]


You just have to set the correct NBT tags, {Amplifier:#,Duration:#}, in your case amplifier value will be 2, duration value will be 480. I can't provide the correct command because I can't test it

You'll need to use NBT notation instead:
/give @a potion[minecraft:potion_contents={custom_effects:[{id:regeneration,duration:480,amplifier:2}]},minecraft:max_stack_size=1]

This tree lists out all the possible values in the potion's data structure:

See Also
